# WSO2 PayloadFactory is sending json wrapped with jsonObject

Tags: api, wso2, json, wso2-api-manager

I am using WSO2 API Manager 1.7.0 and am doing a simple payloadfactory attempting to convert a call from a GET to a POST passing in a json payload.

However when I look at the log files it appears that WSO2 is sending the json wrapped with {"jsonObject": [myjson] }

I am new to WSO2 and am not sure what cofiguration setting I need to use to stop this. I assume it is a config setting since in no examples or documentation that I have found does anyone else mention this.

My api looks like this:

```
"POST http://localhost:81/Service/ProcessRequest HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]" 
"Authorization: Basic asdfadfadfadfadfadfadfa=[\r][\n]" 
"Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]" 
"Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]" 
"activityID: 2342342342342342342342342[\r][\n]" 
"Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]" 
"Host: localhost:81[\r][\n]" 
"Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]" 
"User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]" 
"[\r][\n]" 
I/O session http-outgoing-2-3 11.11.11.11:12345<->192.168.1.1:8080[ACTIVE][rw:w]: 0 bytes written 
http-outgoing-2: Produce output 
I/O session http-outgoing-2-3 11.11.11.11:12345<->192.168.1.1:8080[ACTIVE][rw:w]: 230 bytes written 
"db[\r][\n]" 
"{"jsonObject":{"UserType":"User"}}[\r][\n]" 
"0[\r][\n]" 
"[\r][\n]"
```

The log file part that seems to apply to the service call looks like this:

```
<api name="admin--JJJJJ" context="/jjjjj" version="v1.0" version-type="url">
    <resource methods="GET" url-mapping="/documents">
        <inSequence>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{"UserType":"User"}</format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <property name="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('user:password'))" scope="transport"/>
            <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
            <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
            <log>
                <property name="JSON-Payload" expression="json-eval($.)"/>
            </log>

            <send>
                 <endpoint name="admin--JJJJJ_APIproductionEndpoint_0">
                     <http trace="enable" method="post" uri-template="http://localhost:81/Service/ProcessRequest"></http>
                 </endpoint>
             </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </resource>
    <handlers>
...
    </handlers>
</api>
```

I'm not sure where the db and 0 come from in the transmission but the error I get back from my service appears to be caused by the wrapping jsonObject.

Does anyone have any hints or ideas on how I can either prevent this wrapping or modify the payload just prior to sending it to remove it. Or I guess a better or even different way of transforming a GET request to a POST with a json payload.

Thank you for any hints on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406649/wso2-esb-4-8-json-native-support-trying-to-manipulate-json-and-log-using-media

Answer (score 0):

change the messageformater in axi2.xml (/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml)file as

```
<messageFormatter contentType="application/json" class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>
```

and comment the default message formatter for json

```
<!--messageFormatter contentType="application/json" class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter"/-->
```

learn more on json support here[1]

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/JSON+Support

Answer (score 0):

You can add an enrich mediator to api before send mediator to remove jsonObject wrapper from body like below.

```
<enrich>
    <source clone="true" xpath="$body//jsonObject//UserType"/>
    <target type="body"/>
</enrich>
```

You can add a log mediator after enrich mediator and check the changed body.

Hope this will help you.